# synaptic package will not reload

Tags: package-management

This is the error when trying to reload synaptic manager.
I do not see the duplicates when opening */etc/apt/sources.list*.

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:54 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3
W: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/Release.gpg: Signature by key E5220FB7014D0FBDA50DFC2BE5E86C008AA65D56 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Comment: May you share the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`. Please share it though http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: By the way, you are not getting error. It is warning message. Still it is better it be resolved

Answer (score 2):

For the first sets of lines, *read the actual error message*.  You have entries in both `/etc/apt/sources.list` ***and*** `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`.

Either comment out the lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` or comment the lines out in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  (I'd suggest commenting out the offending line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and let the `google-chrome.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` alone).

---

The last one though about GPG signature being weak is a different issue, and is not one you can fix.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your Synaptic error messages...

In `terminal` type...

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list # view the file
    # note what deb lines the file contains

sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak # backup the file

gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list # edit the file
    # go to line 54 and comment out the line(s) that looks like the deb statement(s) from above
    # do this by placing a `#` character at the beginning of that line(s)
    # save the changes and quit gedit, and close the terminal
```

The last error about the "uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)" is not fixable at your end. Ignore it.